# Moment.js doesn't recognize ISO date format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

While adding a new item to my database I'm creating a new date to it by:

```
const item = new Item({
    author,
    isOrdered,
    name,
    createdAt: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()
  });
```

When sorting items, the moment.js is called and it warns me in the console

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
>   ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
>   reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date
>   formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
>   release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

The date format that I'm saving to db is `2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z`.
I've been reading the documentation and by following the instructions I did something like this, to specify the date format:
`moment('2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z', 'ddd, D MMM YYYY H:m:s Z')`
but still, it throws me a warning. How to workaround this warning?

Comment: you can do directly: `createdAt: new Date().toISOString()`

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` => `new Date()` (but that's tangential to your question).

Comment: It's unclear from this question where moment.js comes into play. There's no code shared which actually uses it at all

Comment: Are you sure the warning/error occurs for `moment('2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z', 'ddd, D MMM YYYY H:m:s Z')`?

Comment: I'm sure. Been testing this solution for a while right now

Comment: Moment does not issue that warning for the string `"2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z"`, which is indeed in [the supported format](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: this `moment(new Date().toISOString())` already works fine. I don't know where are you facing this issue, but it's not where you think it is

Comment: Why would you want to store a date as a formatted string value in the first place? Store the timestamp value, and format it in the desired form (which might perhaps _change_ some day?) only when you output it …

Comment: Also `moment('2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z', 'ddd, D MMM YYYY H:m:s Z')` is wrong. `moment('2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z')` would work or if you insist on giving it a format it should be: `moment('2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD\Thh:mm:ss.SSSZ')`

Comment: @apokryfos - You probably didn't mean to have a tab in that format string (though "The parser ignores non-alphanumeric characters" so...) `moment('2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ')` is correct, I believe.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're probably right. I am probably confusing it with PHP rules which require escaping of literal characters

Answer (score -1):

try to specify the format separately like,

```
moment('2019-01-09T07:55:34.665Z').format('ddd, D MMM YYYY H:m:s Z')
```

'Wed, 9 Jan 2019 15:55:34 +08:00'

Comment: > > When sorting items, the moment.js is called and it warns me in the console

the above workaround can help in format error

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer to see the database applying the timestamp. This would depend a bit on what db and potentially orm you're using.

In javascript, as mentionned in the comments, just do...

```
createdAt : new Date().toISOString()
```